# Question and answer system with upvote

Tags: chatter, appexchange

Is there an existing solution on AppExchange for Questions & Answers system like stackexchange sites (like this one), where you can up-vote, down-vote, and moderate questions with links to a duplicate etc.
We would use this internally as some kind of help-desk for our salespersons.

We are using the chatter for now, but we are receiving a lot of duplicates, and we have a problem of linking new discussions to older ones where we have already answered the question.

p.s. I have tried searching but I'm missing the right name for this kind of app. The only thing I did found was something for Salesforce Communities, and we do not have and do not wish to have a licence for that.

Comment: Apparently there is a private version of stack overflow called "Stack Overflow Enterprise". I've never seen it or used it, but it might be worth looking into: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/company/contact). It's not on the AppExchange though, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds nice, we will take it into consideration. But we would try to avoid our sales having separate accounts and having to leave SalesForce to post a question. I was looking for something that would extend the Chatter functionality.

Comment: What's wrong with Chatter Questions (note: not the older Chatter Answers, the newer one)? It can show duplicates, you can choose the best answer, etc. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Look interesting. I don't see this option in our Org. I will look in to how to enable it, in this help article it claims it is enabled by default.

Comment: I have managed to make it work by adding question action to our global layouts. It has some features, but not all that we need, like marking it as duplicate. But it will do for now, thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @ZoranBasic Glad I could help. You might leave this question open, though, maybe someone will know of an app that does everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

We are working to improve the Q&A experience and are planning to add up & down voting.  Stay tuned...

Comment: by we do you mean salesforce? Are you affiliated? If so glad to see you here. Welcome to SFSE

Comment: Do you maybe know the time frame for this?

Comment: Yes!  I'm one of the Product Managers for Chatter.  Current plan is to make this available in Winter '18 (Safe Harbor of course).  It would be great to hear more about your specific use cases.